# How to make the bootstrap class="label label-default" same width as the input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found examples with the prepend add-on but not the default label. How can make it so the label is the same width as the input?

```
<div class="control-group">
    <span class="label label-default">ChangeOrder Attn</span>
    <input ng-model="ChangeOrderAttn" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably not `Bootstrap` but generally speaking that, the input has `form-control` and that's why it has `width:100%` so simply you may apply this to your `span` or just add `display:block`, in this case, this will also consume `100%` width of it's parent. So, if you create another `class` and use that, for example ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t1ppLrzy/1/)):

**CSS:**

```
.full-width {
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <span class="label label-default full-width">ChangeOrder Attn</span>
    <input ng-model="ChangeOrderAttn" class="form-control" type="text" />
</div>
```

Then the `span` will get `100%` width and this way you can optionally use `.full-width` only when needed. Just modify the behavior by adding another `class`. You may also add other `styles` in that `class` if needed. But, there could be a ready made way in `Bootstrap - 3` using it's native `class`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bootstrap 3, you could set the width for the group and the label like this:

```
<div class="control-group col-sm-12">
    <span class="label label-default col-sm-12">ChangeOrder Attn</span>
    <input ng-model="ChangeOrderAttn" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you want, but the closest thing you can do without custom CSS is:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon label-default">ChangeOrder Attn</span>
    <input ng-model="ChangeOrderAttn" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
```